# I had this script working once to uninstall Office 2013 from registry but now it won't work

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013" } | select UninstallString

#$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013" } | select UninstallString

#if ($uninstall64) {
#$uninstall64 = $uninstall64.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
#$uninstall64 = $uninstall64.Trim()
#Write "Uninstalling..."
#start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall64 /quiet" -Wait}

#if ($uninstall32) {
#$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
#$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()
#Write "Uninstalling..."
#start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall32 /quiet" -Wait}
```

But now when I run it, i get the command line switch for the uninstall 32 part. Not sure what changed, but it was nice that it got rid of all of Microsoft Office 2013 plus, now i have to rely on configuring the config file to uninstall it.

Comment: Your posted code, can't do anything as almost everything is commented out. Remove the # at the beginning of each line and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As per Olaf's comment, currently you get the reg value of the uninstall for 32bit but you then do nothing else as the #'s comment everything out.  To the system all those lines are effectively blank.

Using your code, if you amend it to this it will do something at least:

```
$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013" } | select UninstallString

#$uninstall64 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013" } | select UninstallString

#if ($uninstall64) {
#$uninstall64 = $uninstall64.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
#$uninstall64 = $uninstall64.Trim()
#Write "Uninstalling..."
#start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall64 /quiet" -Wait}

#if ($uninstall32) {
#$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
#$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()
Write "Uninstalling..."
start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall32 /quiet" -Wait
```

This will only do 32bit uninstalls.

Comment: Wait a second I thought I Uncommented those out haha crap. Let me check I know it didnt work.

Comment: Sorry I had comment part of them due to using the config.xml to uninstall 2013 i then added # to every line. Anywoo when using the above code correctly without the #, i started getting the Windows Installer pop up indicating to use switches when using the above code. Makes no sense.

Comment: I would need to use

$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013" } | select UninstallString
if ($uninstall32) {
$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()
Write "Uninstalling..."
start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall32 /quiet" -Wait} 

Again this just brings up the Windows Installer and command line switches

Comment: The script works to uninstall other strings just not microsoft office professional Plus 2013 for some odd reason so i have to mess with the config.xml file and name it SilentUninstallConfig.xml   and use the /uninstall ProPlus /config to point to the source of the silentuninstallconfig.xml

Comment: Ah ok, so have you sorted it now @joextreme?

Comment: Hi Dizzy I think im fine will have to use the Silentuninstallconfig.xml approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using the SilentUninstallconfig.xml with right parameters is the only way to uninstall Office 2013 as of now.